# Avatar And Ping commands, Help me? :D

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have 2 "problems" that I can't solve:

---

First of all:

This is my code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  aliases: ["ping"],
  description: "Show Bot Ping.",
  execute(message) {
    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
    let commands = message.client.commands.array();

    let helpEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("API latency: ")
      .setDescription(`**${Math.floor(message.client.ws.ping)} ms!**`)
      .setColor("#fffff1")
      .setFooter(`Command requested by: ${message.author.tag}`);

    return message.channel.send(helpEmbed).catch(console.error);
  }
};
```

When I use the ping command, everything happens normally...

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/744902402964062262/746774318813413436/API.png

What I want is, in the final part `Command requested by: ColorlessWorld # 9293`, I would like it to display only the user name, that is, `Command requested by: ColorlessWorld`

But I don't know how to do this.

---

Secondly:
This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
 
module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar',
    description: 'returns a users avatar',
    execute(message, args){
        message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
        const { prefix, token } = require ('../config.json');
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 
        if(!message.mentions.users.first()){
            embed.setDescription(`
            **:camera_with_flash:Avatar**
            Use !avatar @NickName.`)
            embed.setColor('fffff1')
            return message.channel.send(embed)
        }else{
            const user = message.mentions.users.first()
            embed.setImage(user.avatarURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: false, size: 256 }))
            embed.setDescription(`**:camera_with_flash:@${user.username}**
            Click [here] to download.`)
            embed.setColor('fffff1')
            embed.setFooter(`Command by: ${user.username}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({format: "png"}))
            return message.channel.send(embed)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do to stay blue where it is [here]? like several famous bots?
`Click [here] to download.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use:

```js
message.author.username
```

---

Secondly, you can use this markdown:

```
[description](https://url.here)
```

`[This is an example](https://example.com)`

[This is an example](https://example.com)